# Facebook SDK loading forever

Tags: javascript, facebook

i'm loading the facebook js sdk via the window.fbAsyncInit function. it's working fine in chrome but in safari and firefox FB.Auth._loadState has the state 'loading' forever and non of the FB.* functions are working.

anyone experiencing the same problem? do i need to set some special headers?

any help would be appreciated.

**update**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>    

<script>

var app_id = <?=conf_app_id?>;

window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.init({appId: app_id, status: true, oauth: true, cookie: true, channelUrl: 'https://www.example.com/channel.html'});        
}

$(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
});
</script>
```

i think it might be an issue with the loadbalancer :( does anyone know if facebook is crosschecking the ip/session or something after loading the sdk?!

Comment: i've added it. it's included at the bottom of the html

Comment: @Oliver, did you ever have any luck solving this or working around it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @BenLee hey :) the problem was caused be the loadbalancer, facebook makes a check back and sets the variables, if the fb request comes to another server than the loading request was started it didn't work. I ended up deactivating the loadbalancer for this host ...